# Creating gender dropdown in Phoenix / Elixir results in "assign @all_genders not available in eex template."

Tags: elixir, html-select, phoenix-framework

I am wanting to Add Gender to a client that comes from a database (and other look up tables)

I have defined the Client as so:

```
defmodule Dropdown.Clients.Client do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Dropdown.Clients.Admin

  schema "clients" do
    field :email, :string
    field :name, :string

    belongs_to :genders, Admin
```

And Gender

```
defmodule Dropdown.Clients.Admin do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "gender" do
    field :gender, :string
    has_many :clients, Client
  end
```

Controller add and create functions are like so:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Clients.change_client(%Client{})
    gender_query = from g in Admin, select: {g.gender, g.id}
    all_genders = Dropdown.Repo.all(gender_query)

    render(conn, "new.html", all_genders: all_genders, changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"client" => client_params}) do

    case Clients.create_client(client_params) do
      {:ok, client} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Client created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.client_path(conn, :show, client))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

The corresponding Context is:

```
    Client
    |> Repo.get!(id)
    |> Repo.preload(:genders)
  end

  def create_client(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %Client{}
    |> IO.inspect()
    |> Client.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end
```

In the Add form:

```
  <%= select(f, :gender_id, @all_genders) %>
  <%= error_tag f, :gender_id %>
```

I have the form show the Gender dropdown, however, when I submit I get an error:

**assign @all_genders not available in eex template.**

The IO.inspect shows:

```
  [debug] Processing with DropdownWeb.ClientController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "ECAXCnJJEw1ZGRtyFmoZDDF_GjQ3CHFzqvxrAypk0JW5N3kkE1UytpBJ", "client" => %{"email" => "george@example.com", "gender_id" => "1", "name" => "George Company"}}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
```

Any suggestions on fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: In `{:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)`. You're missing all_genders assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error case (when `Client.create_client/1` returns an error tuple, you are rendering the `new.html` template again. However, you are not providing the `all_genders` assign (key:value), so when it tries to render, it crashes.

You have to modify your controller to include `all_genders` in the error case as well:

```elixir
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = Clients.change_client(%Client{})
  gender_query = from g in Admin, select: {g.gender, g.id}
  all_genders = Dropdown.Repo.all(gender_query)

  render(conn, "new.html", all_genders: all_genders, changeset: changeset)
end

def create(conn, %{"client" => client_params}) do
  case Clients.create_client(client_params) do
    {:ok, client} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Client created successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: Routes.client_path(conn, :show, client))

    {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
      # This part was missing in your original code
      gender_query = from g in Admin, select: {g.gender, g.id}
      all_genders = Dropdown.Repo.all(gender_query)
      # -----------
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, all_genders: all_genders)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Now need to figure out why there is an error instead of saving the record.

Answer (score 0):

The error was a typo in the changeset. Here is the full Client context

```
defmodule Dropdown.Clients.Client do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Dropdown.Clients.Admin

  schema "clients" do
    field :email, :string
    field :name, :string

    belongs_to :genders, Admin

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(client, attrs) do
    client
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :email, :genders_id])
    |> validate_required([:name, :email, :genders_id])
  end
end
```

And for completeness the Admin as well

```
defmodule Dropdown.Clients.Admin do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "gender" do
    field :gender, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(admin, attrs) do
    admin
    |> cast(attrs, [:gender])
    |> validate_required([:gender])
  end
end
```